# TableLayoutPanel slow because of autosize and/or nested TableLayoutPanels?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have some TableLayoutPanel, where the first "layer" has 1 column and ten rows, some of this rows contain either a UserControl or another TableLayoutPanel with 2 or 3 columns and some rows. One or two of them contain another TableLayoutPanel, but that's it. So that's a maximum of 3 "levels" of nested TableLayoutPanels. Most of these are set to autosize, because some UserControls might change their size. When a form containing such a nested TableLayoutPanel, the UserControls "flicker", it looks like they are loading very slowly.

- Do I use too much autosizing?
- Or is my Panel too nested?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TableLayoutPanel responds very slowly to events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900099/tablelayoutpanel-responds-very-slowly-to-events)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the flicker has to do anything with 'auto-sizing' or 'nested panels'.

Please refer another 'S-O' link : [How to avoid flickering in TableLayoutPanel in c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677533/how-to-avoid-flickering-in-tablelayoutpanel-in-c-net)

Suspend the layout until you've added all your controls on.

```
TableLayoutPanel panel = new TabelLayoutPanel();

panel.SuspendLayout();

// NOW add controls (including nested-controls) -- do autosizing etc

panel.ResumeLayout();
```

Also look at using Double Buffering. You'll have to create a sub-class of the `TableLayoutPanel`. See an [example](http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/09/how-to-create-flicker-free.html).

Hope this helps.